# Sidekiq StatsD Tagging in perform job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, statsd

I am implementing statsd publishing in Sidekiq and I was able to do it successfully, however tags only seem to be added to the "global" statsd messages. As you can see below the `app:` is not appended for the actual `sidekiq.job` messages, all the other messages do have it. Why is this? I'd like for the `app` tag to always be present.

```
sidekiq.processed:16|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.enqueued:0|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.retries:2|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.dead:0|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.scheduled:0|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.busy:0|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.enqueued.low:0|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.enqueued.default:0|g|#app:test-app
sidekiq.job:1|c|#host:MacBook-Pro.local,env:development,name:test_cache_job,queue:default,status:ok
sidekiq.job.time:16034|ms|#host:MacBook-Pro.local,env:development,name:test_cache_job,queue:default,status:ok
```

Here is how I've implemented it in the `sidekiq.rb` initializer.

```
Sidekiq::Pro.dogstatsd = ->{ Datadog::Statsd.new(ENV['DD_HOST'], ENV['DD_PORT'], tags: ["app:#{ENV['APP_NAME']}"]) }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # Middleware for StatsD
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    require 'sidekiq/middleware/server/datadog'
    chain.add Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::Datadog
  end

  config.save_history(Sidekiq::Pro.metrics, 30)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

My colleague just pointed out this to me: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware#client-middleware-registered-in-both-places

I guess this works:

```
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    require 'sidekiq/middleware/server/datadog'
    chain.add Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::Datadog, tags: ["test:app"]
  end
```